# Authenticating flask Application with a decorator

Tags: python, flask

```
def header_authenticate(func):
    def wrapper():
        headers = request.headers
        auth = headers.get("X-Api-key")
        if auth == 'password':
            func()
        else:
            return jsonify({"401": "Authentication credentials failed"})

    return wrapper


@header_authenticate
@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    return "<h3>Welcome<h3>"
```

I want to be able to use the decorator above to authenticate. It does not throw an error but it goes through. I tried placing the decorator below and it also failed.

```
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: wrapper
```

Comment: Swap the position of the decorators and don't forget the `return`.

Comment: I change the position `@header_authenticate` of the  and added the return and the problem persisted